# Lightning DOM XSS Injection Issue Reported in Checkmarx

Tags: lightning-aura-components, checkmarx, soql-injection, xss

After execution of checkmarx report we are facing injection issue for one of our aura lightning component

**Issue reported :**

> The application's <aura:component
> implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:isUrlAddressable"
> access="global" > embeds untrusted data in the generated output with
> url, at line 1. This untrusted data is embedded straight into the
> output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker
> to inject malicious code into the output.

Issue reported at line number 3 of below code

**Code:**

```html
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="testDummyurl" type="String" />
    <iframe scrolling="no" style="position:absolute;top:0px;width:100%;height:100vh;" src="{!v.testDummyurl}" />
</aura:component>
```

Please help me and let me know how we can overcome this injection issue reported by checkmarx

Comment: @sfdcfox please provide your input if possible

Answer (score 2):

The iframe src attribute can be used to execute malicious javascript code (see [here](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Cross_Frame_Scripting)). For example, `testDummyurl` could equal the code below, which would cause an alert message to appear when the user loads the page:

```
javascript:alert('hello')
```

To resolve this issue, you can explicitly set the iframe's src protocol to http / https:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" style="position:absolute;top:0px;width:100%;height:100vh;" src="https://{!v.testDummyurl}" />
```

Comment: Sure Tyler. I will give it a try and will update how it is behaving after the change.